# Removing Records from an Associated Table PHP

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I am working on a Many to Many table and I fixed an issue where I couldn't pull the records. Now I'm trying to delete records when that is needed.

I have a site where children can be associated to an event. In the event that a child was accidentally added I want to be able to remove the child. They are added via Checkbox as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="eventChildren[]" id="childId_12" />
<input type="checkbox" name="eventChildren[]" id="childId_13" />
<input type="checkbox" name="eventChildren[]" id="childId_14" />
```

I have multiple checkboxes that are pre-checked if the child has already been added.

I have three tables (not sure if this is relevant):

```
DB:
- children
- events
- eventChildren
```

When I save the record I'm doing a check to make sure I don't add duplicates to my `eventChildren` table. I know if records are already in the database but not submitted from the form then the child is being removed from the list...and I can't figure out how to catch this subset.

Example code:

```
// $eventChildren comes from the form above name="eventChildren[]"
// $eventId is passed into the function

$currentChildren = $this->eventChildren->GetEventChildren(array('eventId' => $eventId));

// Loop through all submitted children
foreach ($eventChildren as $childId)
{
    // Loop through all existing children
    foreach ($currentChildren as $currChild)
    {
        // If the child ID's do not match then it's a new record
        if ($currChild->childId != $childId)
        {
            $this->eventChildren->AddEventChildren(array(
                'eventId' => $eventId,
                'childId' => $childId
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

When the form is submitted I get a return that grabs all records from the `eventChildren` table where the `eventId` matches.

```
eventChildren (return)
- [0]
    eventChildrenId => 1
    childId => 12
    eventId => 4
- [1]
    eventChildrenId => 2
    childId => 13
    eventId => 4
- [2]
    eventChildrenId => 3
    childId => 14
    eventId => 4

submittedChildren
- [0] => 12
- [1] => 13
```

How can I say, based on the `submittedChildren` array remove the record where `eventChildrenId = 3`?

I hope this makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to approach this(better ways), but I'm just going to go with a straight forward answer I can give based on the info you presented.

```
$orphaned = array();
foreach ($currentChildren as $currChild) {
    if (!in_array($currChild->childId, $submittedChildren)) {
        $orphaned[] = $currChild->childId;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would those better ways be? The current method I'm using does't actually work because I have two ID's 8 and 10. When 10 see's 8 they are not equal so it add the new record and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you're deleting the relationship between the two items (i.e. deleting from the many-to-many table)?

Usually the event_id and the child_id fields would be the identifying (PRIMARY) key in the relationship.  Therefore, if the user submits a child_id of 13, and you can contextually derive that the event_id is 4, then deleting from the eventChildren table where child_id = 13 and event_id = 4 should suffice.  You shouldn't need to first gather information about the eventChildren object (you already have the identifying info).

Comment: Good point. Delete from eventChildren where childId = x and eventId = x...since I'm removing duplicates this shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: There should be a PRIMARY key on those columns (or UNIQUE, if you have an AUTO_INCRMENT column) to prevent duplicates...

Comment: I was running into an issue where every time the form was submitted it would tie the same children to the same event...with a different primary key ID. I would just have a lot of duplicate relationships.

Comment: Set a UNIQUE key, then use INSERT IGNORE ;)